# Update verb for database items C#

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the update verb to prevent duplicate phone number when editing the patient's profile so that the permission to enter the duplicate phone number is obtained during editing, , , but... it comes and checks the same patient and not allows the update of the same  It takes the previous phone... tell me a way to give up on itself and not include itself in the condition, it doesn't matter in the form of a linQ or anything, please guide me.

```
Public bool checkHavePhoneNumber(client c)
{
  Return db.clients.any(i=>i.phonenumber ==c.phonenumbers):
}
```

Thus i'll always get a record. I want this record to be abandoned if it was its previous self

Comment: Wait a second, so I move into a house and get the previous guy's phone number and now you won't let me be a client??

Comment: So,  I am a client and now my wife wants to become a client, too. Who is living at the same address with same land line phone number ... or is this just checked on update?

Comment: Yes, it is checked in the update so that it does not match with other clients... But when I register the edit, I see that he already has a phone number, he does not let the previous one remain in place, because he found himself, this problem  what to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thus i'll always get a record. I want this record to be abandoned if it was its previous self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're querying the Clients table for *all* clients. If `c` already exists in the database, it's going to be included in those results, thus you'll always get a match.

You can have either multiple `Where` clauses or an "and" in your Where/Any to include a filter for the client you are interested in.

```
public bool checkHavePhoneNumber(client c)
{
    return db.clients
        .Where(x => x.Id != c.Id) // change this property as needed
        .Where(x => x.phonenumber == c.phonenumbers)
        .Any();
}
```

Change the `Id` property to whatever property you use to uniquely identify a `Client` record.

Comment: , for example, the blood type is change, but the contact number remains the same as the previous contact number, here so that there are no duplicate contact numbers between the clients  I have set a condition to check whether such a contact number already exists or not, but it comes and finds itself, it finds the same initial contact number, so the contact number must be changed, but I don't want to change the contact number.  , please guide me what code should I write to skip my data inside the condition...

Comment: yes thus i'll always get a record. I want this record to be abandoned if it was its previous self

Comment: it is checked in the update so that it does not match with other clients... But when I register the edit, I see that he already has a phone number, he does not let the previous one remain in place, because he found himself, this problem  what to do

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question with more context, preferably with a [mre]. I've done the best with what you've cared to share so far. If you need something different, please communicate it.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. To the sign! I didn't care about your code. I used it now and answered. Where the ID is not equal, where the contact number is equal to the previous one is edited. The problem was resolved. Thank you